# React - URL gets updated but the page is not rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, rendering

I am following along a beginner's course on React. The Nav. Bar has two options - About, HomePage. On clicking on the bar, the url gets updated but the page remains the same and nav stays. I get no error.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import HomePage from './HomePage';
import About from './About';
import Header from './common/Header';

function App() {
    function getPage() {
        const route = window.location.pathname;
        if (route === "about") return <About />;
        console.log("hi");
        return <HomePage />;   
        }  
    return(
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <Header>
            { getPage() }
            </Header>      
        </div>
    );
    
}
export default App;
```

Header.js

```
import React from 'react';
//to navigate across the website
function Header(){
    return (
        <nav>
            <a href="/"> Home </a> | <a href="/about"> About </a>
        </nav>
    );
}
export default Header;
```

index.js

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import React from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";
import App from "./components/App";
render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

About.js

```
import React from 'react';
class About extends React.Component{
    render (){
        return(
            <>
                <h1> About </h1>
                <p> This is the About Page </p>
            </>
        );
    }
}    
export default About;
```

HomePage.js

```
import React from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
function HomePage(){
    return(
    <div className="jumbotron">
        <h1>
            Welcome
        </h1>
        <p>
            This is my first React Project
        </p>
        
    </div>
    );
    
}
export default HomePage;
```

There is no change in the page, only the URL gets updated.

I have tried many solutions on SO but none worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it always displays the `<HomePage />` component?

That's because `window.location.pathname` returns a path with a leading slash. So `route === "about"` will always be false. You need to check `route === "/about"` instead.

Comment: I tried it but it did not work. It does not always display the <HomePage /> component either.  Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Can you log what window.location.pathname is then?

Comment: Yes, I can. In '/' - home and 'about' - About. I get [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS... on the console.

Answer (score 0):

In getPage function condition is wrong it's not `about` it's will be `/about`
Just change condition in if statement

like this

```
if (route === "/about") return <About />;
```

Comment: I tried it and it did not work. Thanks for your time and effort.